# ¿Por qué no me crea el .png de la imagen seleccionada en la Galería?

Tags: java, android

¿Por qué no me crea el *.png* que estoy intentando que cree de la imagen seleccionada?

```
public class ClaseNueva extends Activity {

    private ImageView imagenPersona;
    private int SELECCIONAR_IMAGEN = 237487;
    private Uri pathImagenUri;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.clase_nueva);

        imagenPersona = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenPersona);


        imagenPersona.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ventanaImagen();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ventanaImagen() {
        try {
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Seleccionar de la galería"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Seleccionar una foto");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    switch (item) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent intentSeleccionarImagen = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            intentSeleccionarImagen.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intentSeleccionarImagen, SELECCIONAR_IMAGEN);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SELECCIONAR_IMAGEN && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (pathImagenUri != null) {

                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                File file = new File(dir, "resized_image.png");

                Uri imagenSeleccionada = pathImagenUri;
                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(pathImagenUri.getPath());

                if (bitmap != null) { //Bitmap no es null?

                    //Redimnsiona imagen.
                    Bitmap bitmapout = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, false);
                    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
                    try {
                        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    bitmapout.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    try {
                        fOut.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        fOut.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error obteniendo imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error obteniendo imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String ruta_imagen) {
        File imagenArchivo = new File(ruta_imagen);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (imagenArchivo.exists()) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagenArchivo.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

No recibo ningún error, simplemente no se crea, ¿A qué se debe?

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas `startActivityForResult()` al recibir los datos de la imagen mediante el bundle en `onActivityResult()`, puedes obtener el path de esta forma crear el bitmap, redimensionarlo y guardarlo en otro path (variable `nuevaRutaArchivo`);

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private ImageView imagenPersona;
private Uri pathImagenUri;
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);


            /*//Muestra imagen seleccionada de galería en ImageView.
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenPersona);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);*/

            //Define path donde sera guardada una nueva imagen con medidas 150x150px
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File file = new File(dir, "resized_jorgesys.png");

            if (!file.exists()) { //Si archivo no existe.
                try {
                    file.createNewFile(); //Procede a crearlo.
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            if (bitmap != null) {

                //Redimensiona imagen.
                Bitmap bitmapout = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, false);
                FileOutputStream fOut = null;
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmapout.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                //Muestra imagen con nuevas medidas en ImageView.
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenPersona);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapout);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error obteniendo imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }




        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }


    }
}
```

Al final la imagen con nueva medida se agrega al ImageView:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola ´perdon, corregí la linea de código :  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, false);

Comment: Esa linea no es necesaria

Comment: nuevaRutaArchivo  es el path donde se guardaría el archivo, lo comento en la respuesta.

Comment: Ok realicé un cambio al código.

Comment: @UserNameYo edité la respuesta pero olvide cambiar esa variable, en realidad es file, es la ruta donde se guardará el archivo, en este ejemplo es de la camara: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), tu puedes definir el path que desees.

Comment: Por favor, podrías actualizar tu pregunta para guiarme un poco más como implementarlo en mi código? Lo he intentando pero no consigo nada, no me guarda la imagen, mañana se termina la recompensa y no me gustaría que se perdiese, y si es dartela a ti mejor, que siempre estás ayudandome, gracias @Jorgesys !

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta siguiendo tu respuesta, no recibo ningún error pero no me crea el .png @Jorgesys

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta de cualquier forma puedes consultar el repositorio, saludos.

Comment: Perfecto! Solucionado este tema! He estado modificando el código para que la la DB obtenga y guarde la ruta de la nueva imagen, pero no me la guarda, he creado una pregunta aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51718/por-qu%C3%A9-mi-sqlite-no-guarda-la-ruta-del-nuevo-png-que-he-creado Muchas gracias por todo, marco como útil y +150 ! @Jorgesys

Comment: Cuando puedas abre un chat nuevo, por favor @Jorgesys

Comment: @UserNameYo hey estas?

Answer (score 1):

Existe La función:

```
 miImagen.getScaledInstance(anchuraNueva, alturaNueva, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

El ultimo parámetro es el algoritmo que se sigue para hacer la redimensión.

Esto usando el paquete **swing**.

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)) para mas información.